# How to generate a single pdf from multiple html pages in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, jspdf

I need to generate pdf of multiple Html pages in single go by clicking button in a web page.

To get the multiple html pages in single html page I used iframe. But when I try to generate pdf from that html file using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js), the iframe are not include in pdf.

Comment: With what do you want to generate them?

Comment: with javascript code, note iframe are of different domain